# Как скопировать информацию с чужого сайта на свой

Tags: php, битрикс

Здравствуйте есть сайт интернет магазин на CMS 1С-Битрикс и надо скопировать страницы ну или хотя бы цену с каждодневным обновлением. Пытался скопировать сайт через оффлайн браузер но за день скачал 40000 файлов (или расскажите как скопировать сайт на cms без взлома базы). Как вы уже наверное поняли я в этом не шарю так что прошу объяснить попроще заранее спасибо. 
Сайт [link text](http://www.amikovry.ru/)

Comment: Доступа нету

Comment: ну что делать… Тогда закажите парсер у того, кто шарит.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

у битрикса есть удобная выгрузка в xml или csv. Воспользуйтесь ею. Она интуитивно понятна, но и описана в документации.

Если же у вас нет доступа в админку, то беда. Писать парсер. А это для нешарящего практически невозможно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ до вас я вообще не знал что такое парсер.

Comment: рада, что смогла помочь. Если честно, не надеялась даже на это. На самом деле не самая простая тема для новичка, но если есть интерес, всё получится. Вот ещё ключевое слово для поиска истины: XPath.

Comment: А не могли бы вы теперь подсказать как сделать сайт.
Парсер выгружает допустим в БД а как сделать чтобы бралась строка с бд и создавалась страница по шаблону с этими данными.

Comment: учите PHP и делаете сайт

Comment: ну-ну-ну, прямо-таки php сразу! :) не надо так пугать человека :) есть же и более удачные языки :)

Но да: как сделать сайт, уж точно не подсказать в одном маленьком комментарии, тут люди годами учатся.

Comment: Ну не сайт хотя бы как сделать чтобы создовалась страница когда появляются записи в бд. Если вам будет удобнее пишите на почту roznik94@yandex.ru

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример "скопированной" страницы:

[отсюда копировали](http://turboam.com.ua/ru/catalogue/goods_list/12)

А [сюда вставляли](http://remont-turbin.net/complekt/korpus_podshipnikov/index.php)

Копировали таблицу, а не интернет-магазин, но из нижеприведенного кода суть будет ясна.

вот код:

```
<div class="no1"><center><p class="opred">Корпус подшипников в сборе (картридж) – это специальный агрегат, конструкция которого состоит из таких частей: корпус подшипников, колеса турбины и компрессора, а также вал. В совокупности эти составные запчасти представляют собой картридж в сборе.</p></center></div>
    <div class="no2"><center><input type="text" maxlength="30" placeholder="Поиск..." id="search_id" autocomplete="off" class="poisk" autofocus/></center></div>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <center><img src="img/eskiz.jpg" alt="Актуатор"></center>
</div></div><table class="goods-list" id="table_tag"> 
<thead> <tr> <th style="width:3%">№ п/п</th> <th style="width:7%">Наименование</th>  <th style="width:30%">Примечания</th>  <th style="width:50%">Применение</th>  </tr> </thead><tbody class="123">
<?php
$dir = "img/";
$name = scandir($dir);
$urlo=file_get_contents('http://www.turboam.com.ua/ru/products/show/CHRA');
$urlo=str_replace('<span id="1461565809897S" style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span>', '', $urlo);
$urlo=str_replace('<p>&nbsp;</p>', '', $urlo);
$urlo=str_replace('<span style="font-size: smaller;">', '<span style="font-size: 14px; text-align: left;">', $urlo);
$urlo=str_replace('<td><p>', '<td>', $urlo);
$urlo=str_replace('<li style="text-align: justify;">', '<li style="text-align: left;">', $urlo);
$urlo=str_replace('<p>', '', $urlo);
$urlo=str_replace('</p>', '', $urlo);
$urlo=str_replace('<p> </p>\n<p> </p>', '</ol></td>', $urlo);

for($i=2; $i<=(sizeof($name)-2); $i++)
{
    $file = basename($dir.$name[$i], ".img");
    $m=$i-1;    
    #откуда будем парсить информацию:
    $content = $urlo;    
    //начало забираемого контента: 
    $pos=strpos($content, 'AM.'.$file.' </a> </td>   <td>');
    //Отрезаем все, что идет до нужной нам позиции: 
    $content=substr($content, $pos); 
    //Таким же образом находим позицию конечной строки: 
    $pos=strpos($content, '</td>  <td>');
    //Отрезаем ненужное: 
    $content=substr($content, 0, $pos); 
    //Если встречается код, который нам ненужен, вырезаем его: 
    $content=str_replace("AM.$file </a> </td>   <td>", '', $content); 
    $content=str_replace('</td>  <td>', '', $content); 
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $lst = $urlo;    
    //начало забираемого контента: 
    $del=strpos($lst, $content.'</td>  <td>');
    //Отрезаем все, что идет до нужной нам позиции: 
    $lst=substr($lst, $del); 
    //Таким же образом находим позицию конечной строки: 
    $del=strpos($lst, '</td>  </tr>'); 
    //Отрезаем ненужное: 
    $lst=substr($lst, 0, $del);
    //Если встречается код, который нам ненужен, вырезаем его: 
    $lst=str_replace("$content</td>  <td>", '', $lst);
    $lst=str_replace('</td>  </tr>', '', $lst);
    if($lst=='-')
    $lst='<center>-</center>';
    echo "<tr><td>$m</td><td><a href='".$dir.$name[$i]."' title='$file'>$file</a></td><td>$content</td><td class='tri'>$lst</td></tr>";
}?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Естественно, такой код - один сплошной костыль, и любые изменения на сайте, с которого собрались "копировать", будут оказывать сильное влияние и на ваш сайт.
Он применим и к интернет-магазинам, если достаточно хорошо освоить этот способ. Но опять же, надо ли оно вам?